# Create score for comaparison of algorithms

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python, algorithms

The following graph gives the results from a test. The y axis shows the MAPE (error) which should be minimum, the x-axis shows the epochs which should also be minimum.

[image: results]

As one can see two algos are competing with each other. This is not always the case, on a different test some other might be dominating. So, I want to create some scoring for the algos for comparison purpose.

Also, I want to know how to get the saturation point (epoch) at which the MAPE saturated. The MAPEs are stored in a list in python.